# Definition of OBR in OSGI specs?

Tags: osgi, obr

Does anyone know where OBR (OSGI Bundle Repository) is defined in the OSGI official specs? I looked at Core, Compendium and Enterprise, and couldn't find it.  :( Can someone point me to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a draft here: http://www.osgi.org/download/rfc-0112_BundleRepository.pdf I don't know the details but this RFC has been going on for ages. I think the delay might have something to do with Eclipse P2 competing to be a better repository reference. Maybe someone else can clear that up?

Comment: Wow, how did you find that? Hehe.

Comment: For one, it's liked from the Felix pages, http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html